Error while doing npm run dev in vite+react project
(https://i.sstatic.net/wi9rcQTY.png)
Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0:
  1 │ import.meta.url

Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0:
  1 │ import.meta.url

Downgraded the Nodejs to 20.18.1 still not able to run the app also react and react-dom are already installed
any idea how to resolve this???
Nodejs version- 20.18.1
windows OS
IDE- VS code
